# Upload múltiplo para servidor online PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho a seguinte função para envio múltiplo de imagens:

```
//Diretório onde a imagem será gravada temporariamente
$dirToSave = 'assets/uploads/'.$pasta.'/'.$tipo.'/';
if(!is_dir($dirToSave)){
    echo "noa tem";
    mkdir($dirToSave, 0777, TRUE);
    chmod($dirToSave, 0777);
}

//Limite do tamanho máximo que a imagem deve ter
$length         =   5242880; //5 MB por arquivo

//Extensões permitidas para os arquivos
$fileExtension  =   array( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png' );

//Inicializa os parametros necessários para upload da imagem
$this->files->initialize( $dirToSave, $length, $fileExtension );

//Verifica se alguma imagem foi selecionada
$image         =   isset( $_FILES[ $campo ] ) ? $_FILES[ $campo ] : null;



if( !is_null( $image ) ) {

    //Seta o arquivo para upload
    $this->files->setFile( $image );

    //Processa o arquivo e recebe o retorno
    $upload  =   $this->files->processMultFiles($campo);

    //Verifica retornbou algum código, se sim, ocorreu algum erro no upload
    isset( $upload['code'] ) ? 'mensagem de erro' : null;

    foreach($upload as $valor){
        $fotos['int_id'] = $cod;
        $fotos['inf_tipo'] = $tipo;
        $fotos['inf_imagem'] = str_replace('assets/uploads/'.$pasta.'/'.$tipo.'/', "", $valor['file']);

        if(preg_match('%assets/uploads%', $fotos['inf_imagem'])==true){

        } else { 
            $this->adicionar('interno_fotos', $fotos);
        }
    }
}
```

Porém, eu uso este sistema em LOCALHOST, e preciso enviar as fotos para um SERVIDOR.
De que forma eu posso fazer para enviar para o servidor ao invés de enviar para um localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Única forma de enviar o arquivo de imagem para outro servidor seria enviando a imagem via FTP para este servidor.

Tendo em mãos endereço do servidor, usuário FTP e senha, segue exemplo:

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' )
{
        var_dump( $_FILES );//apenas para debug


        $servidor = 'host';
        $usuario_ftp = 'lalalala';
        $senha = '1234';
        $pasta_do_ftp = '/httpdocs/uploads/';
        $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];

        $con_id = ftp_connect($servidor) or die( 'Não conectou em: '.$servidor );
        ftp_login( $con_id, $usuario_ftp, $senha );

        ftp_put( $con_id, $pasta_do_ftp.$arquivo['name'], $arquivo['tmp_name'], FTP_BINARY );
}
?>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="arquivo" />
                <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Se o usuário tem acesso FTP ao servidor, ele não poderia então enviar o fonte PHP para o servidor, via cliente FTP, e então fazer lá a mesma coisa que ele fazia em localhost, sem nenhuma implementação adicional?

Comment: Neste caso ele deixou explicito que utiliza o sistema localhost e que gostaria de salvar as imagens em um servidor externo, este era o problema.

Comment: @C.Bohok Não, a ideia é justamente um upload externo, e usando localhost, porque trata-se de sistemas instalados em vários outros desktops que precisam rodar em localhost, pois usam componentes externos (leitor biométrico) e não pode ser 100% online.

Answer (score 0):

FTP **não** é a única forma que pode usar, na verdade tem várias. Aliás, se você já vai rodar nesse PC de destino das imagens o servidor FTP, poderia rodar qualquer servidor. Outras formas de implementar podem ser:

- **`SFTP`** - é muito parecido com o FTP normal, porém através de uma conexão segura ([exemplo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-sftp.php#71197) e [ajuste do exemplo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-sftp.php#121200)).
- **`SCP`** - é um método para cópia segura de arquivos entre máquinas diferentes (manual para [ssh2_scp_send](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ssh2-scp-send.php)).
- **`PHP`** - pode usar um servidor Apache com PHP para expor um serviço que receba o arquivo e salve no local correto, praticamente o mesmo que você já tem para `localhost`.